# React Jest/Enzyme - Snapshots created files are too big (thousands of lines) / Remove attributes from snapshot

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

Everytime I create a snapshot for a specific component, it returns thousands of lines for it (like 80k)
because it is showing an attribute called "theme" for a lot of selectors.
how can I get rid of this attribute. I don't think it is necessary for me to test those things.

Info about the project:

- React cra
- Grommet for components
- JEST/ENZYME for tests

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I need to see your component code to send you the exact solution, but I'm pretty sure the `theme` in your case is being sent as part of the component's spread-operator-notation (e.g. `{...rest}`) and ultimately is being forwarded to the DOM, or something along those lines.

To avoid this behavior, try to deconstruct the `theme` from the spread notation and see if it still getting to the DOM.

For example,

```
// assuming props include `theme` prop
export const App = ({...props}) =>{
    const [theme, ...rest] = props;
    return <Box {...rest} /> // Box should no longer include theme and it won't appear on the DOM (i.e. the tests snapshots)
}
```

If you are not using the `theme` the component from the first place (which might be the case because it was never deconstructed), it might be a good practice not to send it to the component from the first place and avoid the overhead of deconstructing it.

Good luck!